# WordPress get last insert id from database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get the last inserted id from the database I have tried many code am not able to get last insert id. I have given below the following my code. Please any one help and save me.

```
            $users_table = $wpdb->prefix."users";
            $saveFieldArray=array('user_login'=>'$utilisateurCand',
                                'user_pass'=>'$passeCand',
                                'user_email'=>'$emailCand', 
                                user_registered=>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
        $wpdb->insert( $users_table, $saveFieldArray);
        echo $wpdb->last_query;         
        echo $lastInsertId = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Comment: if you use `wp_insert_user` it will return the user ID on success and a wp_error on failure. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/

Answer (score 0):

Basically - if you use WPs own function, then you get the ID on success

Like this.

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login' =>  $utilisateurCand,
    'user_pass'  =>  $passeCand,
    'user_email' =>  $emailCand,
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

// On success.
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo "User created : ". $user_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user(
array(
    'user_email'  =>  $emailCand,
    'user_pass' => $passeCand,
    'user_login' => $utilisateurCand,
    'role' => 'customer'
    )
);
if ( ! is_wp_error($user_id) ){
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $emailCand );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true, false );
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
}
```

Tested & works.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code in my project to get the **last inserted ID** in wordpress, I paste my code below, Hope it helps you.

```
// While use wp_insert_post() use the below code
$post_ID = wp_insert_post($post);
print_r($post_ID);
```

> Returns the ID of the post if the post is successfully added to the database. On failure, it returns 0 if $wp_error is set to false, or a WP_Error object if $wp_error is set to true.

When you used  **$wpdb->insert()** function to store data in table, you can use below code.

```
$wpdb->insert()
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

I hope this will helps you.